# JavaScript Template Literal Interpolation rgba() value

Tags: javascript, templates, interpolation, literals

I have a function:

```
let drawCircle = (str_ID, cx, cy, r, svgfill, stroke) => {
    let drawing1 = document.getElementById(str_ID);
    drawing1.innerHTML = 
    `<svg height=${svgWidth} width=${svgHeight} viewBox='0, 0, 100, 100'>
        <circle cx=${cx} cy=${cy} r=${r} fill=${svgfill} stroke=${stroke} />
    </svg>`;
    console.log(drawing1.innerHTML)
};
```

And when I call it with the following variables:

```
let cx = 50;
let cy = 50;
let radius = 40;
let svgFill = 'rgba(100, 200, 250, 1.0)';
let svgStroke = `#D00000`;

drawCircle('1_svgcirclediv', cx, cy, radius, svgFill, svgStroke)
```

This is what the function evaluates to (logged to the console):

```
<svg height="250" width="250" viewBox="0, 0, 100, 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="rgba(100," 200,="" 250,="" 1.0)="" stroke="#D00000"></circle>
    </svg>
```

Notice how mangled the rgba value is? What is going on here?

Comment: You need to add quotes to the value so that it gets treated as a proper element attribute. The way you have it will make the html string be `fill=rgba(100, 200, 250, 1.0)` which will get fixed by the browser to be what you ended up with. You need it to be `fill="rgba(100, 200, 250, 1.0)"`, so add the quotes to your `svgFill` variable

Comment: Patrick.  Thanks that worked (obviously ;-).  I have looked all over gOOgle for WHY this is.  Is there some link you can provide that explains how that substitution works?  I find it unexpected that strings are not interpolated as, well... strings.  Meaning I would have thought that a quoted string would just be substituted as a quoted string.  The interpolation is "stripping" the quotes?

Comment: They are interperted by js as strings. But, in your code you didn't have quotes in the string itself. The quotes that you used are for the js engine to know that it is working with a string instead of say a number literal and therefore not part of the characters in the string.  For example `t=''` is an empty string with no characters while `t='""'` is a string with 2 characters(double qoute characters).

Comment: OK, but the stroke value ('#d85b49') for example.  The quotes were inserted automagically in the substitution, although extra quotes were not included as part of the string.?.?  Further, if you remove the space from the rgba() value, js will then interpret the string as a string and insert the quotes.

Comment: JS isnt adding anything into the string, it is how the browser's html parser is handling the html string you give it. As long as the value following the `=` is continous(no white space characters breaking it up) the html parser will treat it as the value for that attribute. As soon as it sees a white space character it treats whatever comes after as a new attribute, hence why you get something like `200,=""` it saw the `200,` as a new attribute as there was a break before it. Then when you get the html back out of the element, eg `innerHTML` it is going to give you properly quoted attributes.